# PHP precision rounding question

Tags: php

Wanted to as a simple question.

Code:

```
$myarray = array(5.0000);
echo round($myarray[0],2);
```

Ouput:

```
5
```

Why is the output 5 and not 5.00 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't show the 0's after the decimal point if there are only 0's.

5.050 would be shown as 5.05...

you can have a look at the **[number_format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)** function if you want to show the 0's.

Answer (score 2):

It's because `round` actually rounds off the *data* you give to it, it doesn't change how that data is *printed.*

If you want to specify how the data is *output,* look into using `printf`, such as:

```
printf ("%.2f\n", $myarray[0]);
```